# How to deserialize this JSON with VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I have this JSON data:

> {"asks":[["0.26039995",19.91610429],["0.26063345",3070.562292]],"bids":[["0.26000017",30381.45513902],["0.26000000",8299.1410574]],"isFrozen":"0","seq":50663190}

I wrote this code:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim wc As New WebClient
    Dim sURL As String = "https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnOrderBook&currencyPair=USDT_STR&depth=" & 2
    Dim res As String = wc.DownloadString(New Uri(sURL))

    Dim m As IEnumerable(Of Rootobject) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of IEnumerable(Of Rootobject))(res)
End Sub


Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property asks As asksDef()
    Public Property bids As bidsDef()
    Public Property isFrozen As String
    Public Property seq As Integer
End Class

Public Class asksDef
    Public Property priceAsk As String
    Public Property quantAsk As Integer
End Class

Public Class bidsDef
    Public Property priceBid As String
    Public Property quantBid As Integer
End Class
```

I've pasted the JSON class with VB paste special.
The question is: how to access to every `ask`, every `bid` and the `isFrozen` and `seq` values.

I got an error on this line:

```
Dim m As IEnumerable(Of Rootobject) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of IEnumerable(Of Rootobject))(res)
```

The error message I got is:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in
>   Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object
>   (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[poloniexAPI.Rootobject]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g.
>   [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET
>   type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type
>   like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object.
>
> Path 'asks', line 1, position 8.

I'm stuck again this time with this JSON model. How to proceed with this?

> {"BTC_BCN":{"id":7,"last":"0.00000042","lowestAsk":"0.00000043","highestBid":"0.00000042","percentChange":"0.00000000","baseVolume":"179.56364789","quoteVolume":"436786711.33832335","isFrozen":"0","high24hr":"0.00000043","low24hr":"0.00000039"},"BTC_BELA":{"id":8,"last":"0.00002091","lowestAsk":"0.00002097","highestBid":"0.00002091","percentChange":"-0.10831556","baseVolume":"12.57891843","quoteVolume":"579476.06165462","isFrozen":"0","high24hr":"0.00002345","low24hr":"0.00002088"}}

Comment: The JSON you are working with should be part of the post since it is integral.  `As Object` is wrong - you should create a class to hold the 2 values per "item".  We dont know what the data represents, so use your knowledge of it to create them. That code wont compile, the property declarations should be `...asks As ClassName()` or make them IList.  Finally, I dont think the `RootObject` is a collection.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour] - data essential to the problem and error messages need to be in the post iteself

Comment: Now that I can see the JSON, it is pretty creepy - those Bid/Ask pairs, `["0.26039995",19.91610429]` means it is an array with a string and a decimal (not Integer).  Well, you cant mix datatype like that and use Option Strict.  Personally, I would write a converter so the other code doesnt have to wrestle with it.  Define `asks` and `binds` as `As List(Of JArray)` and you can reference them as `m.asks(0)(1)`  However, they are `J/Object` so you will need to cast them as you use them.  The *other* error is as I said, the root object is not a collection.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Thanks for your response, but: the error i show nothing to see with decimal/integer definition. In all your professional exposition, i get nothing of help. If i have all the knowledge you are talking about, i will have not post the question. Resuming: thanks for nothing. You have a lot of knowledge... for yourselve.

Comment: "Root Object is not an enumerable/ collection" == get rid of IEnumerable.  No one is holding out on you. Read all the words.  Even those like *read [ask] and take the [tour]*

Comment: @SomeOneMore With your latest edit it looks like you are asking a new question. The general policy on StackOverflow is [one question per question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post). Instead of editing this post to ask a new question, [close out this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it was answered to your satisfaction, then [create a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) post altogether so that it can be handled/answered separately.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this specific error is that your JSON represents a single object (which contains some arrays and other info) but you are trying to deserialize it as if the whole thing were enumerable.  However, fixing this will not solve the whole problem; there are a couple of other issues as well.

This JSON is a little odd because it uses an array to group together each price and quantity pair for the bids and asks, whereas an object seems like it would be more appropriate (and more easily consumable).  Since Json.Net does not have a facility to automatically map an array into class properties by index, you will need to use a custom `JsonConverter` to deserialize this data properly.  Also, the prices are represented as strings for some reason where they should be decimals like the quantity.  This can be handled in the converter as well.

Before we get to the converter, let's fix your class definitions.  Since the bids and asks use the same structure, I would recommend defining a common class for that.  Both `price` and `quantity` properties should be declared as `Decimal`:

```
Public Class PriceQuantityPair
    Public Property price As Decimal
    Public Property quantity As Decimal
End Class
```

Then define your root class like this:

```
Class RootObject
    Public Property asks As List(Of PriceQuantityPair)
    Public Property bids As List(Of PriceQuantityPair)
    Public Property isFrozen As String
    Public Property seq As Integer
End Class
```

Here is the code for the converter, which will translate the array structure for each pair into a `PriceQuantityPair` instance:

```
Class PriceQuantityPairConverter
    Inherits JsonConverter

    Public Overrides Function CanConvert(objectType As Type) As Boolean
        Return objectType Is GetType(PriceQuantityPair)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ReadJson(reader As JsonReader, objectType As Type, existingValue As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer) As Object
        Dim ja As JArray = JArray.Load(reader)
        Dim pair As PriceQuantityPair = New PriceQuantityPair()
        pair.price = ja(0).ToObject(Of Decimal)()
        pair.quantity = ja(1).ToObject(Of Decimal)()
        Return pair
    End Function

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property CanWrite As Boolean
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides Sub WriteJson(writer As JsonWriter, value As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer)
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub
End Class
```

To use the converter, add a `<JsonConverter>` attribute to the `PriceQuantityPair` class like this:

```
<JsonConverter(GetType(PriceQuantityPairConverter))>
Public Class PriceQuantityPair
    ...
End Class
```

Finally, deserialize the JSON into the `RootObject` class like this:

```
Dim root As RootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(json)
```

Here is a demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dDHLtR

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand your question.
You can access the properties with the 'm' variable where you are storing the de serialized data.
Ex: m.isFrozen, m.seq, m.bids() & m.asks().

Comment: i got an error on the line "dim m as IEnumerable..." about the definition of the JSON...