# deserialize JSON without one by one, multiple properties

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I have this JSON:

> {"JOE":{"id":7,"age":"23"},"BILLY":{"id":8,"age":"29"}}

i have [this solution for a more simple JSON structure posted by RajN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48118180/1070452).

```
Dim j1 As String = "{ "JOE"":""0.90000000"",""JOE"":""3.30000000"",""MONROE"":""1.20000000""}"
Dim dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(j1)
For Each kvp In dict
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key & " - " + kvp.Value)
Next
```

I'm looking for how to do with the new JSON data.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Now you need a class to hold multiple bits of data.  You should do some research on working with JSON so you dont have to ask the same question with only very minor variations over and over

Comment: [We both know thats not true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47873706/how-to-deserialize-this-json-with-vb-net#comment82715635_47873706) rather you have a history of not understanding what you are given (and then lashing out).  Again, no one is holding out on you - if you want to store more that one piece of data, you will need a class to hold them.  Now, may the Google be with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution very is nearly the same as [the other solution you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48118352/10263) by @RajN, except instead of using `Dictionary(Of String, String)` you need to use `Dictionary(Of String, T)` where `T` is a class that you define to hold `id` and `age`.

So, define a class:

```
Public Class PersonData
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property age As String
End Class
```

Then deserialize:

```
Dim json As String = "{""JOE"":{""id"":7,""age"":""23""},""BILLY"":{""id"":8,""age"":""29""}}"

Dim dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, PersonData))(json)

For Each kvp In dict
    Console.WriteLine("name: " & kvp.Key)
    Console.WriteLine("id: " & kvp.Value.id)
    Console.WriteLine("age: " & kvp.Value.age)
    Console.WriteLine()
Next
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HMv7Om

Make sense?